# Is there any concave and strictly increasing function ‎ with the following properties?‎

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convex-analysis, monotone-functions, functional-inequalities

Let ‎$‎f:[1, +\infty)‎‎\rightarrow‎‎\mathbb{R}‎‎‎$‎ be a function such that ‎$‎‎‎‎‎\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}‎f(n) = 0‎$‎, and put
 ‎$‎f_{\sigma}(x) := \sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k) - f(k+x)‎$‎.

Note that the above series is convergent if $f$ is monotone, convex or concave (see https://www.ijmex.com/index.php/ijmex/article/view/60).

Now, we are looking for a such function with the following properties:

(a) ‎$‎f‎$ ‎is ‎concave ‎and strictly ‎increasin‎g,

‎(b) ‎‎$f_{\sigma}(x-1)\geq F(x) - F(1)$,

where, $F$ is a primitive function of ‎$‎f‎$ (so $F(x) - F(1) = \int_{1}^x f(t) dt$),

‎(c) ‎The ‎function‎ ‎$‎‎‎‎‎f_{\sigma}(x) ‎‎ - ‎\frac{1}{2}‎f(x) - F(x)‎$ is convex on ‎$‎[1, +\infty)‎$‎.‎

Note. One can show that the above conditions imply $‎‎‎‎‎f_{\sigma}(x) ‎‎ - ‎\frac{1}{2}‎f(x)$ and $F(x)$ are both convex. I tried and I found some examples, such as‎‎‎ ‎$‎‎‎f(x) = -x^r$‎ for ‎$‎r<-1‎$‎‏ ‎‎w‎hich‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‏‎it ‎satisfied ‏‎the conditions (a), (b) but it does not ‎satisfy ‎the condition (c)‏.

‎‎‎‎ Thanks‎ in advance.

Comment: You say that "f is increasing", "f is convex", and also that "f(n)- f(n+1)= 0".  If f is **strictly** increasing  f(n+1) must be larger than f(n) so "f(n)- f(n+1)= 0" is impossible.  If f is "increasing" but not "strictly" then it cannot be convex.

Comment: @user247327 $f(n) - f(n+1)$ is not zero, but the limit at infinity is.

Comment: Oops!  I need to get my glasses fixed!

Comment: user247327. $f$ is concave.

Comment: Consider the function $f(x) = -x^{-2}$. It  satisfies the conditions (a) and (b). Also, the second derivative is $\frac{6 x^4\zeta(4, x+1) - 2 x +3}{x^4}$ (for condition (c)). Now, my question : Is $6 x^4\zeta(4, x+1) - 2 x +3\geq 0$ for $x\geq 1$?